# How can this Django Rest Framework Serializer (used to validate a json) be simplified?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, json-deserialization

So I have the following "json":

```
a = {
  "ranks": {
        "top_list": [5, 224, 232, 234],
        "top_dict": {
            "start": 696,
            "end": 704
            },
        "top_id": 8
  }
}
```

and the following serializers (which works):

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class TopDictSchema(serializers.Serializer):
    start = serializers.IntegerField()
    end = serializers.IntegerField()

class RanksSchema(serializers.Serializer):
    top_list = serializers.ListField()
    top_dict = TopDictSchema()
    top_id = serializers.IntegerField()

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ranks = RanksSchema()
```

Combining them like this:

```
MySerializer(data=a).is_valid() == True

> True
```

Can the serializers be simplified?

Comment: what do you mean by "simplified"?

Comment: `TopDictSchema` and `RanksSchema` are only ever used by `MySerializer` so maybe`ranks =` could be set to something better than `RanksSchema`.